# Rtpproxy start with /var/run/ instead of /var/run/rtpproxy

Tags: permissions, rhel

I am currently setting up rtpproxy in RHEL 7, and when I tested in in ubuntu, it runs without any problem.
From what I observe, I think the problem is mainly due to the permission of **/var/run/**; the service fails to start and logs this error:

```
rtpproxy: can't bind to a socket: /var/run/rtpproxy.sock: Permission denied
```

Is there any way to change the way rtpproxy run with **/var/run/rtpproxy/** rather than **/var/run/** ?

[image: rtpproxy can't bind to a socket: /var/run/rtpproxy.sock: Permission Denied]

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://www.rtpproxy.org/doc/master/user_manual.html#idm647)

> `-s ctrl_socket`
>
> This parameter configures rtpproxy control socket. The control socket is used by the call controller for the purpose of creating, modifying, and deleting RTP sessions. The control socket can also be used to fetch stats from the rtpproxy process, or about specific media sessions. Format of ctrl_socket is :. Following types are supported

You probably need to edit `/etc/systemd/system/rtpproxy.service` or, if this is not existant, copy it over from `/usr/lib/systemd/system/rtpproxy.service` and edit it then.

Sadly the part for the config file is missing from the docs, and as I can't install rtpproxy atm, I can't help you with that.

EDIT: I don't think that rtpproxy will actually start, even after that edit, because if the service can't create the socket in cause of wrong permissions, it probably can't create a subdirectory either...

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, `systemctl edit` can be used to do the right thing in all cases.

Comment: I already edited it via systemctl edit and vi, but still the error is persist, and the folder is not pointing to subdirectory which "var/run/rtpproxy/" but still in "var/run"

Comment: Did you run `systemctl daemon-reload` after modifying the systemd service?

Comment: Yep, I did, but still failed